# migrate wordpress site with database to windows azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, migrate

I have a wordpress site with database. I need to migrate that site to windows azure. How to proceed with that. I don't want to create a new wordpress site. I need to migrate the existing site to azure

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated the wordpress website from different server to Azure Web App using the plugin and it is easy and working for me.

Download the plugin [WP Clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) on your existing Wordpress site and, activate it and create a backup. You will get a url which you need to copy.

Second, you need to Create a new Wordpress site in an Azure Web App. Again, download the plugin [WP Clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) on your Azure Wordpress site and activate the plugin. Select restore the and paste the url link which you copied from your another Wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the general steps:

1. Create a new Wordpress site in an Azure Web App from the marketplace.
2. Transfer your content from the existing Wordpress site. This will involve using both FTP to transfer files and also doing a database backup and restore.
3. Setup your custom domain name in Azure when you're ready.

There are details in this series: http://www.davebost.com/2013/07/11/moving-a-wordpress-blog-to-windows-azure-part-4-pretty-permalinks-and-url-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving from a Linux VM you can use this tool that I wrote:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Apache-Migration-Tool

If you are moving from a Windows VM you can use this tool that I wrote:

[www.movmetothecloud.net](https://www.movemetothecloud.net)